# Use WP Title instead of custom field to call

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-title

Someone helped accomplish this code last week which works perfectly,  it pulls keywords entered into a custom field ( advanced custom fields ) into the middle of a URL and then redirects them.

Code in custom single template:

```
<?php $url = get_site_url(); $id = get_the_ID(); echo "<a href='{$url}/goto/amazon/{$id}/'>More info Test dynamic Amazon</a>"; ?>
```

Code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    global $wp_query;
    if ($goto = get_query_var( 'gotoamazon' )) {
        $keywds = urlencode(get_field('amazon_keywords',intval($goto)));
        $link = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&field-keywords={$keywds}&linkCode=ur2&tag=AFFID";
        wp_redirect($link);
        exit;
    }
});
```

Rewrites also in functions.php :

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_rewrite_tag('%gotoamazon%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^goto/amazon/(.*)/?','index.php?gotoamazon=$matches[1]','top');
});
```

But what id like to do now is use the same code to pull the wp_title if the keyword field is empty,  I have the conditional setup, Ive then copied the code from above changing it to the title ( or what i thought would work ) but its not inserting the title into the desired place.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    global $wp_query;
    if ($goto = get_query_var( 'gotoamazon' )) {
        $keytitle = urlencode(wp_title(', '),true,intval($goto));
        $link = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&field-keywords={$keytitle}&linkCode=ur2&tag=AFFID";
        wp_redirect($link);
        exit;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing too many arguments to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

WordPress provides a couple of useful functions for these situations. [`add_query_arg`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) is a helper to build a URL with query arguments, and [`esc_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) provide sanitation and validations relevant to encoding URLs.

Also, [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) will display or return a combination of the page/post title and a seperator, which doesn't seem to be what you need. I'm assuming you want the page/post title, so I've used the [`get_the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) function and passed it the `Global $post` variable.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){

  if ( ! is_singular( 'post_type_key' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  Global $post;
  $default = get_the_title($post);
  $keytitle = get_query_var( 'gotoamazon', $default );
  $args = array(
    '_encoding' => 'UTF8',
    'camp' => '1634',
    'creative' => '19450',
    'field-keywords' => $keytitle,
    'linkCode' => 'ur2',
    'tag' => 'AFFID'
  );
  $link = add_query_arg($args, 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/' );
  wp_redirect( esc_url( $link ) );
  exit;
});
```

Comment: Sorry Andrew,  I should have said the URL provided is an affiliate link so it needs to retain its structure.  So the wp_title will basically replace the search keywords where "{$keytitle}" is in the URL, which has the AFFID at the end. ( apprently amazon are funny about any part of their URL's being removed ) I did try your code to see if it worked, but im getting the same result where no keywords(wp title) are being passed to amazon as a search

Comment: Have amended the code to retain the structure of the link. Can you tell me the file you're running your code from? Is it in `functions.php`?

Comment: Hi Andrew,  yes the code is running from functions.php.    The first bit of code i posted above is then running from a custom single.php .  So when the link is clicked, it should goto the amazon URL , inserting the wp title into the middle of the URL ( which makes amazon search for a certain type of product )

Comment: Tested the new code and it does the same unfortunately